# How to determine player field of vision but on a chess board

Tags: javascript, algorithm, grid, tiles, chess

This is for a chess/board game.

The player's vision range are stored as an array of coordinates relative to the player's position.

```js
// Example:
[
  { x: 0, y: -3 },
  { x: -2, y: -2 },
  { x: -1, y: -2 },
  { x: 0, y: -2 },
  { x: 1, y: -2 },
  // and so on
]
```

The vision range are hard-coded because they are meant to be like chess where the chess piece can only move in certain direction relative to their current position.

There are also bushes on the board. Their coordinates on the board are stored in an array.

```js
// Example:
[
  { x: 5, y: 5 },
  { x: 5, y: 6 },
  { x: 5, y: 7 },
  { x: 6, y: 7 },
  { x: 7, y: 7 }
]
```

My current way of calculating the field of vision is roughly like this:

1. How many bushes there are, then how many line equations there will be.
2. The equations are derived from the coordinates of the bushes and the player.
3. The lines are then extrapolated outwards until they reach the edge of the vision range.
4. All points (or boxes) that happen to be on the extrapolated line segment will be removed.

[image: board-1]
[image: board-2]

The problem is, some points won't be excluded if the bushes have irregular shapes. (Marked with purple boxes in the diagram above).

I have also read up on [38239309](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239309/optimize-field-of-vision-algorithm-in-a-grid-tiled-map), but for that case, the tiles have a fixed size in pixels while mine do not.

and since:

- This is a board game, treating the bushes as [geometrical shapes](https://legends2k.github.io/2d-fov/) is probably not the best idea;
- relying on plain old y = mx + C would yield inaccurate output

Is there another method that I can use to determine the field of vision?

---

## Update

I've been wrecking my brains for a while and it seems like maraca's idea from the comments allowed me to come up with a solution with minimal changes to my existing algorithm. I might have misinterpreted maraca's idea but it ended up working. It just happens so that this is the chess piece with the largest vision range. It would probably still not work if the vision range is the entire board since adjacent cells of adjacent cells are not checked (might be possible if some sort of recursion is involved), but at least for now there are no more "leaky" visions:

[image: no leaky visions]

Still, I believe I'll need to strengthen my mathematical knowledge and revisit this topic in the future if I really want to come up with an algorithm that can work regardless of vision range.

Comment: 1) Write an equation for line L 2) For every bush B, for every pixel p in B, test if the coordinates of p satisfy the equation for L 3) If at least a pixel of B satisfies the equation for L, remove the square for B and all subsequent squares from the squares visible with line L.

Comment: Note that the algorithm described in my previous comment can be optimised *a lot* because if you do things in a smart order you don't need to check every bush for every line.

Comment: Did you mean for every coordinate instead of pixel in step 2? Because it's a board game, unlike some where the player can move pixel by pixel. By the way, you mentioned optimization, do you mean treating the bushes as one thing like a group/line (Eg: in the screenshot, an L-shaped structure)?

Comment: From my understanding of your question, it is a board game, with a square grid, but the bushes have a shape which is smaller than one square, and you want to find out whether a line of sight intersects with a bush, or goes through the bush' square without going through the bush. The bush is a set of pixels inside the square. If my understanding is incorrect, please add more details.

Comment: Instead of calculating line equations it will probably be much easier to use a couple of ifs. E.g. if adjacent tiles in west and nord-west are bushes then the purple tile at the top is not visible and so on. Even for the simpler cases ifs are probably easier than line equations.

Comment: @maraca: from my understanding, the bush is not a whole tile, only part of a tile; see the sentence "The problem is, some points won't be excluded if the bushes have irregular shapes. (Marked with purple boxes in the diagram above)." in the question. Of course I might be wrong; this needs further clarification by the OP.

Comment: There's a bunch of prior art from people making roguelike games.

Comment: Well, from the latest edit of the question, and in particular from the video, it looks like the bushes are whole squares after all. But I don't understand what the sentence `The problem is, some points won't be excluded if the bushes have irregular shapes. (Marked with purple boxes in the diagram above).` means in that case.

Comment: @Stef My apologies for not being clear enough. By irregular shapes, I'm referring to when the bushes are arranged in cross / L-shape / C-shape patterns rather than being arranged in 1x1, 2x2, 3x3, … patterns on the board.

Comment: A couple appoaches posted as comments due to being only links: https://fadden.com/tech/fast-los.html https://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I know this question is a bit old, but I wanted to answer it anyways (if not for you then for anyone else who may need something like this in the future).

My initial idea was to define the bushes as ranges rather than numbers; i.e. if square 5, 2 is a bush then the bush is actually (in mathematical syntax) `{x: 4.5 <= x <= 5.5}{y: 1.5 <= y <= 2.5}`. Now, unfortunately you seem to be using javascript or something because comments are `//` and I only know python, so I can't give you the actual code you'd use. However, I will define the answer mathematically, so anyone using any language should be able to implement this answer.

Because it looks like you want vision to be whole squares (a square is either lit up or not, it can't be half-visible half-behind cover like in real life), we can simply check, for every potential vision square (diagram *a*), if the line from the center of the player-square to the center of the target-square contains any points shared by one of the bushes (diagram *b*).

Now, in order for a line to pass through a two-dimensional polygon, it must pass through one of it's sides. So one could run a simple algorithm on the line vs. the four border edges of the square. It is simple to test if a line passes through an edge, by seeing if they have an intersection using a mathematical equation. set the lines equal to each other, find the intersection point by solving the equation for x and y, and then see if that point is within the range of the border line.

However, the edges of the bushes are parallel to the x and y axes so we can't use the [traditional method](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordintersection.html). However, it also makes it a bit easier because for the lines parallel to the x axis we need only find the x value as the y value is constant.

mathematically speaking, given horizontal edge `y = a  {x: x1 <= x <= x2}` and line `y = mx + c` we equate the two, and see if x is within the range of the edge.

```
mx + c = a
mx = a - c
x = (a - c) / m
```

It's the same for the y value: given vertical edge `x = a {y: y1 <= y <= <2}` and line `(y - c) / m = x`, we check if y is within the range of the edge.

```
(y - c) / m = a
y - c = am
y = am + c
```

do this with all the edges, and you see if the line passes through the shape at all. Do that with all the bushes and all the squares, and you'll see which square can be seen and which cannot.

**Index:**
diagram *a*: The vision of player (p) where each square (o) is visible:

```
        o  
    o o o o o 
    o o o o o 
  o o o p o o o
    o o o o o 
    o o o o o 
        o
```

diagram *b*: The vision of player (p) given obscuring bushes (b) where each square (o) is visible and each square (x) would be visible were the bushes not there:

```
        o  
    x o o o o 
    x x o o o 
  x x b p o o o
    x b b x o 
    x x x x x 
        x
```